# R: how to remove a specific entry in a list

Tags: r, list

```
mylist <- list(
    left = structure(list(y = -10, x = 10, grad = -10.5), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame"), 
    right = list(
        left = structure(list(y = c(7, 8), x = c(20, 25), grad = c(6.5, 7.5)), row.names = 2:3, class = "data.frame"), 
        right = structure(list(y = -7, x = 35, grad = -7.5), row.names = 4L, class = "data.frame"), 
        check_val = 140.166666666667), 
    check_val = 120.333333333333
)
```

I have a `list` object that looks like the following:

```
> mylist
$left
    y  x  grad
1 -10 10 -10.5

$right
$right$left
  y  x grad
2 7 20  6.5
3 8 25  7.5

$right$right
   y  x grad
4 -7 35 -7.5

$right$check_val
[1] 140.1667


$check_val
[1] 120.3333
```

In my list, I have `check_val` stored. I want to check each of these `check_val`, and if the value is > 130, I want to remove the corresponding sublist.

In `mylist`, I would first check `mylist$righ$check_val` and see that `140.1667 > 130`, so I want to remove the entire `mylist$right` sublist. Then I check `mylist$check_val` and find that `120.333 < 130`, so I will not remove anything.

I want the final output to be

```
> output
$left
    y  x  grad
1 -10 10 -10.5

$check_val
[1] 120.3333
```

It's possible that `mylist` can have many sublists, i.e., there could be a `check_val` embedded in `mylist$right$right$right$left$right$check_val,` so I wanted to write code that would take care of those cases. This is what I have so far, but does not give the correct output. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
for(i in 2:length(mylist)){
  print(i)
  if(length(mylist[[i]]) == 1){
    if(mylist[[i]] > 130){
      mylist[[i]] <- NULL
    }else mylist[[i]] = mylist[[i]]
  }else if(length(mylist[[i]]) > 1){
    if(mylist[[i]]$check_val > 130){
      mylist[[i]] <- NULL
    }else mylist[[i]] = mylist[[i]]
  }
}
```

@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ EDIT @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

Suppose now I have `mylist2`

```
mylist2 <- list(left = structure(list(y = -10, x = 10, grad = -10.5, sim_score = 110.25, 
    output = -10.5, criterion = "x < 15"), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame"), 
    right = list(left = structure(list(y = c(7, 8), x = c(20, 
    25), grad = c(6.5, 7.5), sim_score = c(98, 98), output = c(7, 
    7), criterion = c("x < 30", "x < 30")), row.names = 2:3, class = "data.frame"), 
        right = structure(list(y = -7, x = 35, grad = -7.5, sim_score = 56.25, 
            output = -7.5, criterion = "x >= 30"), row.names = 4L, class = "data.frame"), 
        root = list(root = structure(list(y = c(7, 8, -7), x = c(20, 
        25, 35), grad = c(6.5, 7.5, -7.5), sim_score = c(14.0833333333333, 
        14.0833333333333, 14.0833333333333), output = c(2.16666666666667, 
        2.16666666666667, 2.16666666666667), criterion = c("x >= 15", 
        "x >= 15", "x >= 15")), row.names = 2:4, class = "data.frame"), 
            check_val = 140.166666666667)), root = list(root = structure(list(
        y = c(-10, 7, 8, -7), x = c(10, 20, 25, 35), grad = c(-10.5, 
        6.5, 7.5, -7.5), sim_score = c(4, 4, 4, 4)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -4L), class = "data.frame"), check_val = 120.333333333333))
```

and using `clean_list` returns the following:

```
> clean_list(mylist2, M = 130)
$left
    y  x  grad sim_score output criterion
1 -10 10 -10.5    110.25  -10.5    x < 15

$right
$right$left
  y  x grad sim_score output criterion
2 7 20  6.5        98      7    x < 30
3 8 25  7.5        98      7    x < 30

$right$right
   y  x grad sim_score output criterion
4 -7 35 -7.5     56.25   -7.5   x >= 30


$root
$root$root
    y  x  grad sim_score
1 -10 10 -10.5         4
2   7 20   6.5         4
3   8 25   7.5         4
4  -7 35  -7.5         4

$root$check_val
[1] 120.3333
```

However, ideally I would want

```
$left
    y  x  grad sim_score output criterion
1 -10 10 -10.5    110.25  -10.5    x < 15

$root
$root$root
    y  x  grad sim_score
1 -10 10 -10.5         4
2   7 20   6.5         4
3   8 25   7.5         4
4  -7 35  -7.5         4

$root$check_val
[1] 120.3333
```

Is there a way to modify `clean_list` so that it can remove the entire `mylist2$right` sublist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this gets what you want -- note that I've specifically required `data.frame` elements to be skipped (so any `check_val` nesting within a `data.frame` will go unnoticed)

```
THRESHOLD = 130
clean_list = function(x, M = THRESHOLD) {
  if (is.data.frame(x) || !is.list(x)) return(x)
  if ('check_val' %in% names(x) && x$check_val > M) return(NULL)
  out = lapply(x, clean_list)
  out[lengths(out) > 0L]
}

clean_list(mylist)
# $left
#     y  x  grad
# 1 -10 10 -10.5

# $check_val
# [1] 120.3333
```

Comment: You can remove the nulls with `Filter(length, lapply(x, clean_list))`

Comment: @r2evans that won't work recursively though right? just the top level... I tinkered a little bit with "assign to `NULL`" to remove them from the output but I'm not sure it's possible with the functional approach

Comment: I wrote almost the same function and it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks @r2evans for improving this answer, it now works as required & still compact. If you look at `print(Filter)`, you'll see internally it does `lapply`, which means it will be slower than tailor-made `lengths` for this use case

Comment: @MichaelChirico Thank you so much. I have a quick follow up question with a new list called `mylist2`. It has another layer of nesting, but `clean_list` didn't take care of it the way I thought it would. Would you mind taking a look at my editted post? Otherwise I can also post it as a separate question if that would be more appropriate. Again, thanks so much for your help.